# how to vertically align a div inside another div with unknown height

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

Please help me to vertically align a div inside another div with unknown height(auto) of the parent div.

This question is already answered few times, but they have used fixed height for parent div.

Hence please help on this, I need to align child div vertically middle to parent div. Below is the code I have used.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-9">
<div>AAAA</div>
<div>AAAA</div>
<div>AAAA</div>
<div>AAAA</div>
<div>AAAA</div>
<div>AAAA</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 parent">
<div class="child">
<div class="nom_bt">button</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  display: table;
  height:auto;
}
.child {
    width:130px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;  
}
```

I have two columns, so that I need to align second column vertically middle to the 1st column

Comment: What's the problem with your code? It is working perfectly fine. It neatly aligns the child to the parent vertically without explicit height on parent.

Comment: @Abhitalks, I have two columns, so that I need to align second column vertically middle to the 1st column

Answer (score 0):

Making the child class:

```
     display:inline-block;
     top:50%;
     position:relative;
```

and your parent class:

```
     display:table-cell;
```

should do the trick!

Comment: @ArunKumarM does using min-height rather that heigth;auto; improve things?

Comment: transform: translateY(-50%); try this alongside top:50%;

Comment: @ArunKumarM i don't like this but try all with position absolute

Comment: @ArunKumarM no problem, i guess that didn't work? unfortunatley i cannot prepare a fiddle at the moment

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
    display:table;
}
.col-sm-9{
    display:table-cell;
}
.col-sm-3{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This should work with your markdown: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xz9q9qwg/)

Comment: I have tried from this link also, they have used fixed height,

Comment: even I have tried using all options in this article, but it is not working if we have not mentioned static height.

Comment: That is a working solution, so it should be that I didn't get the question properly, could you give some more code (html) and details?

Comment: added html code, parent div needs flexible height and child div height can be static(30px)

Comment: Changed answer. In your case it is more about how to set div 100% height of parent, which is not so easy, so I used dysplay:table in css, is it ok?

Comment: @ Lunokhod, Thank you for your help, but it is not working when we add bootstrap files and also this concept will not work for me. Because, layout will change in smaller devices. Hence I cannot use dysplay:table for .row